# python call method on uninstantiated class

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi i have a class in my Python 3.5.2 code:

```
class Foo(object):
    __description__ = "Description of Foo"

    def get_description(self):
        return self.__description__
```

Now i can call get_description on in instance of Foo:

```
foo = Foo()
foo.get_description()
Out: "Description of Foo"
```

If i don't have an instance available i could do:

```
print(Foo.__description__)
Out: "Description of Foo"
```

But in my code i really don't want to have direct access to __description__, since i abstracted my code furter down the line to use
get_description on other classes (Bar, Baz, etc) which don't have a __description__ but generate the description in another way using a get_descripton() method.

So is it wise, doable or unadvisable to do:

```
Foo.get_description(Foo)
Out: "Description of Foo"
```

It seems to work but looks rather ugly to me, is there a better way to do it without having to instatiate Foo. In reality my Foo objects are a thousand lines of code with dozens of methods, and it seems wrong to having to instantiate them when i really only need the staticly defined   __description__

I'm probably missing some things here but could someone please explain to me why my way of thinking is probably a bit flawed here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a classmethod.

```
class Foo(object):
    __description__ = "Description of Foo"

    @classmethod
    def get_description(cls):
        return cls.__description__
```

Now you can call the method directly on the class: `Foo.get_description()`.

(Note, it is discouraged to create your own double-underscore attributes, as these are reserved for Python's internal use; just use a standard name, eg `description`.)

Comment: Thanks pretty straight forward, i forgot about classmethods, i was fiddling around with staticmethods  which can't access self or cls attributes. Simple!

Comment: The double underscores are because in reality Foo is a class that inherits from SQLAlchemy ORM models. Where all the non-underscored lines are interpreted as Columns or other model-specific attributes (relations, foreignkeys etc). That's why the SQLAlchemy ORM  itself also uses for example \__tablename__ to specify the database table. If you would use "tablename" it would be interpreted as a column-attribute of the model. Django puts that stuff in the Model's "Meta"-class where you can use "normal" attr names. SQLAlchemy doesn't provide that.

Answer (score 2):

Two ways:

First is `@classmethod`:

```
class Foo(object):

    @classmethod
    def get_description(cls):
        return "Description of Foo"

print(Foo.get_description())
```

Second (I think a better way) is `__doc__`:

```
class Foo(object):
     """Description of Foo"""


print(Foo.__doc__)
```

Comment: Or combine both `@classmethod def get_description(cls): return cls.__doc__`